# Adding row to DataGridView (Form1) from Form2

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I know there are a lot of questions about this, and a lot of answers... but I'm still trying to make this work.

OhMyVisitorsMW is my Form1, FormAddWebsite is my Form2.

Here is the code of my Form1 :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class OhMyVisitorsMW : Form
    {
        private int nbroflinksadded = -1;
        FormAddWebsite FormAddWebsite = new FormAddWebsite();

        public OhMyVisitorsMW()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OHMyVisitorsMW_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
            {
                if (e.RowIndex == nbroflinksadded+1)
                {
                    FormAddWebsite.ShowDialog();
                }  
                else
                {
                    contextMenuStrip2.Show(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y); 
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddSite(string nomsite, string urlsite)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(nomsite, urlsite);
            dataGridView1.Update();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code of my Form2 :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class FormAddWebsite : Form
    {
        public static string nomsite;
        public static string urlsite;

        public FormAddWebsite()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OhMyVisitorsMW MainForm = new OhMyVisitorsMW();
            nomsite = textBox1.Text;
            urlsite = textBox2.Text;
            MainForm.AddSite(nomsite, urlsite);

            this.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong.. ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using event handlers to do something like this. Read following sample. This is not a real form. I just created sample classes to demonstrate.

```
public class ParentForm : Form
{
    Button openButton = new Button();

    public ParentForm()
    {
        openButton.Click += openButton_Click;
    }

    void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
        childForm.OKButtonClick += childForm_OKButtonClick;
        childForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    void childForm_OKButtonClick(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Use properties from event args and set data in this form
    }

}

public class ChildForm : Form
{
    Button okButton = new Button();
    TextBox name = new TextBox();
    TextBox address = new TextBox();

    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> OKButtonClick;

    public ChildForm()
    {
        okButton.Click += okButton_Click;
    }

    void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OKButtonClick != null)
        {
            MyEventArgs myEventArgs = new MyEventArgs();

            myEventArgs.Name = name.Text;
            myEventArgs.Address = address.Text;

            OKButtonClick(sender, myEventArgs);
        }
    }
}

public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't know this method! I actually like it very much. I can have a better organisation in my code. Thank you for the help, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Everytime in the button click you are adding the website details to a new instance of the `OhMyVisitorsMW`.

```
OhMyVisitorsMW MainForm = new OhMyVisitorsMW();
nomsite = textBox1.Text;
urlsite = textBox2.Text;
MainForm.AddSite(nomsite, urlsite);
```

You have return the data to the instance from where you have shown the `FormAddWebsite.ShowDialog();`. This can be achieved in multiple ways.

Set the `FormAddWebsite.Parent = this` before showing the dialog and in the button_click handler

```
OhMyVisitorsMW MainForm = Parent as OhMyVisitorsMW();
```

Or add public properties in `FormAddWebsite` for getting the entered data and  call `AddSite` after `FormAddWebsite.ShowDialog();` with the data from these public properties.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I understand better now :). However I changed to using event handlers (see other answer), because I prefer this method.

Comment: @WilliamGéraldBlondel - Glad to help :) As I mentioned in my answer, there are multiple ways to achieve your requirement.